Balloon Air Physics
Is there any possible way to attach an inflated balloon to an object, in such way that the balloon will deflate through a path at a realistic rate and push the object?

Hi, Gamer ... I think since this will be at least partially a fake, we have to know what kind of pushing.. Along rails? Through the air?  preferably illustrate.. we like pictures, here :)
